Multivariate Random Normal Distribution with Conditions
I'm working on a simulation model that will serve as the basis for classifying empirically derived archaeological data. I'm working in R and using a bounded version of mvrnorm() to simulate 8 projectile point (i.e., arrowhead/spearhead) dimensions (max length, axial length, max width, etc.) with a correlation matrix derived from the empirical dataset. The simulated data are then subject to culture transmission rules and projected for n generations to simulate the effect of different social learning scenarios. Most of the artifact dimensions are significantly correlated and several must have specific relationships in order for my simulated artifacts to be realistic. For example, axial length cannot be larger than max length because they would be one in the same. I have tried to adjust the mvrnorm function by adding conditions that need to be satisfied including upper and lower bounds. I've tried rejection sampling during simulation and adjustment after the simulation. However, in both cases, the resulting covariance matrix for Gen 1 is pretty far off the original covariance matrix that I'm trying to duplicate in Gen 1. I'd like to find a solution that: 1) results in a Gen 1 correlation matrix very close to what I see in the empirical data; 2) results in simulated measurements that fall within bounds established by the empirical dataset (min and max observed values); and 3) satisfies the conditions for realistic artifact measurements.
Here's an example of how I've tried adjusting records after the simulation, which seems to be the least problematic of the methods but still results in a signficantly different covariance matrix in Gen 1:
adjust_simulated_data <- function(data, traits, mu, Sigma, bounds, 
                                  max_iterations = 10) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  p <- length(traits)
  
  # Define conditions to check
  check_conditions <- function(row) {
    c(
      row["LengthAxial"] <= row["LengthMax"],
      row["WidthBasal"] <= row["WidthMax"],
      row["WidthNeck"] <= row["WidthMax"],
      row["PSA"] <= row["DSA"]
    )
  }
  
  # Resample individual rows that violate conditions
  for (iteration in 1:max_iterations) {
    violations <- logical(n)
    
    # Check for violations
    for (i in 1:n) {
      row <- data[i, ]
      conditions <- check_conditions(row)
      if (any(!conditions)) {
        violations[i] <- TRUE
      }
    }
    
    # Exit loop if no violations remain
    if (!any(violations)) {
      message("All conditions satisfied after ", iteration, 
              " iterations.")
      break
    }
    
    # Resample violating rows
    for (i in which(violations)) {
      # Preserve non-trait columns
      non_trait_columns <- data[i, !(names(data) %in% traits), 
                                   drop = FALSE]
      
      # Resample traits using mvrnorm_bounded with the original param_list values
      resampled_traits <- mvrnorm_bounded(
        n = 1,
        mu = mu,
        Sigma = Sigma,
        bounds = bounds
      )
      
      # Update the data row with resampled traits
      data[i, traits] <- resampled_traits
      data[i, !(names(data) %in% traits)] <- non_trait_columns
    }
  }
  
  # Warn if max iterations reached
  if (any(!violations) && iteration == max_iterations) {
    warning("Max iterations reached; some constraints may still be violated.")
  }
  
  return(data)
}


Let's start by considering what your question is really about: is it about multivariate normal distributions (or truncations thereof) or, as I suspect, is it really about how to model these eight characteristics?  And if it's the latter, what information, data, and assumptions do you have that bear on the matter?
